# Freeze on Copying APK file

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a **new empty project**, switched platform to **Android** and started **Build and Run**. But when it comes to **"Copying APK File to device"** it just freezes and I have to restart Unity.

I installed **Android SDK & NDK tools** just before that (through Unity Hub). **Android Build Support** was installed by me manually a while ago so it was visible as installed in **Add Modules** window. I did not do any changes to the project. The most interesting thing is that the **apk is built in my Builds folder**. Not sure if it works though.

I am using Unity 2019.1.0f2. The device Android version is 9.0 (API level **28**) and the minimum API set in Player is **16**, so the problem should not be with API.

Does anyone know possible reasons for it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn off the following setting on your android device.

Settings -> Developer options -> Monitor apps installed by ADB

This setting(if turned on) will ask a verrification if you want to install the app. It feels like this cuts off the connection with unity which causes it to get stuck.

Unplugging and replugging the device seems to work aswell. In case of big projects this is anoying tho since if you are to quick it will just say it lost connection and it will ask if you want to reconnect, which in turn causes the same problem.

Comment: Thank you! My device didn't gave me a notification, but unity just got stuck. After disabling that option it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only answer that worked for me:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1248123/build-run-apk-freezes-on-pushing-content-only-one.html

In short, Player settings -> Publishing settings -> Split application binary

Answer (score -2):

First of I would ask you on what computer did you run this on? (performance wise)

Second you can just copy the .apk file to the phone and install it there. If you got to where it prompts for copying to android your apk file is fine and built.

Comment: I checked the load with Task Manager. Everything is normal. About uploading .apk on my phone - it will be super slow in terms of iteration time.